# Android status bar tints from kitkat to lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat, android-appcompat

I'm trying to implement the nice status bar for my app and have successfully achieved this on kitkat.

This is the xml I'm using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>       
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: Status bar on kitkat]

However on lollipop it doesn't have the nice gradient effect. It's just a darker colour.

[image: Status bar on lollipop]

How can I make the lollipop status bar look like the kitkat one?

Comment: For my two pence. I actually prefer it without the gradient.

Comment: a) What phuzi said. b) On kitkat the implementation of translucent status bar is different from lollipop and we can't change neither from code.

Comment: Ok, so it's not really possible then. I'm suprised you both prefer the non gradient version. I think it's quite nice. Each to their own though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint) library developed by [Jeff Gilfelt](https://github.com/jgilfelt)