# How to get lollipop status bar on kitkat

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop, android-statusbar

I'm trying to achieve that `Status bar` with `PrimaryDarkColor` And `PrimaryColor` like Lollipop on Kitkat and here is my try:

```
<style name="PopularTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkPopular</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimaryPopular</item>

    <!--here is what I've added to try to get transparency -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Also, I test this method with https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint but it won't be my choice because I'm using another color for each activity.

How to achieve that status bar with `PrimaryDarkColor` and `PrimaryColor` in Kitkat?

Result:

[image]

Comment: use Android Design Support Library

Comment: @user5114910 - could you please give me an example ? :|

Comment: refere this link https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/ . If you are using eclipse then download Android Design Support Library Project and add it to your project dependency. hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked here on the app I work at how we do it.

First remove everything from under `<!--here is what I've added to try to get transparency -->`, we have nothing of those on our style. However it works the AppCompat theme or activity already does for you.

and then you add the extra rule for Kitkat:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private static void setupWindowKiKat(Window window) {
   window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
}
```

and call it from your activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT &&
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     setupWindowKiKat(getWindow());
```

it is possible that you can add this to a `values-v19\style.xml` but above it's how it's on our app. Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah, thank you.but after add these codes it will be like this : http://i.imgur.com/O5zjzjC.png how can i add my `PrimaryDarkColor` with this TRANSLUCENT_STATUS ?

Comment: sorry I just reviewed the code from our git repo, there's an extra comparison. You only call that for Kitkat, not for Lollipop.

Comment: i need this to be something like this first picture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469276/android-status-bar-tints-from-kitkat-to-lollipop?lq=1

Comment: and i'm trying to add my own color with:       `window.setStatusBarColor(PopularActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDarkPopular));` how can do that? getResources have a error

Answer (score 0):

You Should first root Your device, then go to Google play store and install (Wanam Xposed) http://repo.xposed.info/module/ma.wanam.xposed 
open it and follow some steps right there then install (Xposed installer) http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer
Then open this last Go to "download" and look for "Flat style colored bars" download and install it then go back to Modules activate it and reboot your phone and You will see the changes.
I hope i helped. i works great for me on ace 4 Sm-g316hu

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible because they both run on a different API (lollipop on  20, 21 or 22).

Comment: it's a hack, so, i saw that working on kitkat but, i need a exactly method to do !

Comment: ow okay, you need to be rooted and have xposed framework ready to use, you go to download and search for Material Status Bar then install, reboot and DONE

Comment: i need to do this programatically, not with root or something like this! check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469276/android-status-bar-tints-from-kitkat-to-lollipop please read the question and answer if you have a good method or working method!